# How to display validation message with french symbols in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-validation

In Laravel validation a made rules to validate my fields, when I got an error it's shows me this error without french symbols

> [["Le cin a d\u00e9j\u00e0 \u00e9t\u00e9
> pris."]]

Instead of showing this message :

> Le cin a été déjà pris.

NOTE : I translated the messages from english to french in `\ressources\lang\en\validation.php`

I made this code in `AppServiceProvider` in `boot` function but does'nt work :

```
Blade::setEchoFormat('e(utf8_encode(%s))');
```

How can I resolve this ?

Comment: Try editing the file and saving with utf-8 charset

Comment: Already done ! This is the first thing we do in the head of files

Comment: i have the same issue, it 's not only in blade, but in api and unit test,
when you write $response->assertSee(trans('lang.errorMessage')); it always be assertion error

Comment: Make sure that, your IDE/Editor also pointed to **UTF-8**

Comment: i' m using phpStorm, and global encoding and project encoding is utf-8

Comment: I work with Visual Studio Code

Comment: any luck with this issue?

Comment: No @OMR I did not found the solution

Comment: I'm working with a lot of language on laravel, and everything works well. Even the validation too. Dont know why you both getting this error @OMR

Comment: I used my all language validation code from here https://github.com/akaunting/akaunting/tree/master/resources/lang @OMR

Answer (score 0):

Append within HTML head tags:

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you try it?

```
Blade::setEchoFormat('e(utf8_decode(%s))');
```