# non decoded lang messages in unit test in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, unit-testing

Normally, when I build a unit test, I make some assertions to be sure of my app workflow.

In some cases, I make unit tests just to make sure in this case there will be an error and that error must have this certain message.

For example, when the user is 17 years old, and he tries to rent a car, the message should be "you can't rent a car in this age".

But when I make this message from local translate file, the message comes in non-decoded format.

The unit test would look like:

```
/** @test */
public function testUserAge()
{
    $user = factory(User::class)->create(['birth_date' => Carbon::now()->subYears(17)]);
    Passport::actingAs($user);
    $rentCar = factory(RentCar::class)->create();
    $response = $this->post('api/rentCar/'.$rentCar->id);
    $response->assertSee(trans('lang.wrongUserAge'));
}
```

The problem is, when the local language is English, everything is fine, but for other languages, especially non-Latin languages, it always fails.

The output is similar to:

> Failed asserting that '{"success":false,"message":"The given data was invalid.","errors":{" wrongUserAge":["\u0648\u0642\u062a \u0627\u0644\u062d\u062c\u0632 \u0642\u062f \u0645\u0636\u0649"]}}' contains "*the message text in another language witch comes from lang file*".

How can I make my unit test green regardless of the locale language?

Currently, I'm solving this by setting the locale to English manually in the (setup function) in my test class.

I have found some similar questions like [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63243159/10573560).

But even those questions have no answers.

Answer (score 0):

It is a late response but I am posting the next person with the same un-answered question. I was able to pass my French validation text by encoding the expected text. Example using the original piece of code

```
/** @test */
public function testUserAge()
{
    $user = factory(User::class)->create(['birth_date' => Carbon::now()->subYears(17)]);
    Passport::actingAs($user);
    $rentCar = factory(RentCar::class)->create();
    $response = $this->post('api/rentCar/'.$rentCar->id);
    $response->assertSee(json_encode(trans('lang.wrongUserAge')), false);
}
```

Hope it saves time for someone someday

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: thanks a lot, but it is not a solution to my answer, I want to get the result from the response right, not decode the local message
as I said, for temporary solution I am using app()->setLocal('en') , it is better than decoding lang message